# How to send a message to a public Telegram channel by php?

Tags: php, api

Is it possible to send a message to a public Telegram channel by API as admin?
I mean is it possible to send e.g. a video to a public Telegram channel by using e.g. php?

Comment: Apparently - it's possible: https://core.telegram.org/method/messages.sendMedia

Comment: Does it post like an admin posts a message? I mean if the users can discriminate the difference between api posted message and a real one?

Comment: is there any onw having issues with telegram api? mine not working properly from last few days nov 2019,

Answer (score 30):

You can create a telegram bot and add it to your channel as admin.
Then use @yourchannel as chat_id in your telegram bot for sending messages to your channel.
As an example in php:

```
<?php
$botToken = "yourbottoken";
$chat_id = "@yourchannel";
$message = "your message";
$bot_url    = "https://api.telegram.org/bot$botToken/";
$url = $bot_url."sendMessage?chat_id=".$chat_id."&text=".urlencode($message);
file_get_contents($url);
?>
```

Comment: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request

Comment: request should be in `POST` method.

Comment: @Mortezaipo Just when you want send a file it should be in POST method. Otherwise you can use both POST and GET methods.

Comment: Or use TelegramBot, here is an example from someone which I successfully adapted: https://github.com/php-telegram-bot/core/wiki/How-to-send-message-to-channel-user-without-user-interaction